# Auto-formatting in Wordpress posts only

Tags: wordpress

I'm using `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` in my theme in order to disable Wordpress auto-formatting that adds paragraphs everywhere and often messes up the layout.

However, one of my clients wants to be able to add blog posts on his own. He needs to be able to format his blog posts from the WYSIWYG editor, minimally to have paragraphs.

Is it possible to allow the auto-formatting in blog posts only, or in posts of a particular type or belonging to a particular category?

So far all examples and articles I found use the exact same code as the one listed above. I also checked the https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags but didn't see anything there that could help me solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So now that you've removed the regular wpautop filer, you could add your own in its place, and in it, only apply the wpautop only on posts of type "post":

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'smart_autop' );
function smart_autop($content) {
    $post = get_post();
    if($post->post_type != 'post') return $content; // if not a post, leave $content untouched
    return wpautop($content);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked like a charm!